# yarn dev error Command failed with exit code 1 when running guest-book example

Tags: visual-studio, nearprotocol

I'm trying to use `yarn dev` to run the guest-book example following the [guest-book example](https://github.com/near-examples/guest-book#quick-start), but this is what I got:

```
Computer@Summerbook MINGW64 ~/Documents/VS Code Projects/near apps/guest-book (master)
$ yarn dev
yarn run v1.22.11
$ yarn build:contract:debug && near dev-deploy && nodemon --watch assembly -e ts --exec yarn dev:start
$ asb --target debug
'asb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I think the error is this:

```
'asb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

The script in package.json is:

```
 "scripts": {
    "build": "yarn build:contract && yarn build:web",
    "build:contract": "asb",
    "build:contract:debug": "asb --target debug",
    "build:web": "parcel build src/index.html --public-url ./",
    "deploy": "yarn build && near deploy && gh-pages -d dist/",
    "dev": "yarn build:contract:debug && near dev-deploy && nodemon --watch assembly -e ts --exec yarn dev:start",
    "lint": "eslint \"./**/*.js\" \"./**/*.jsx\"",
    "start": "yarn deploy && parcel src/index.html",
    "dev:start": "env-cmd -f ./neardev/dev-account.env parcel src/index.html",
    "test": "yarn build:contract:debug && asp && jest"
```

I've tried installing dependencies again, but it didn't work.
I believe I'm running under the same directory as package.json.
What can I do here? What causes the error with 'asb'? Thanks for any help!

Comment: `yarn` and then `yarn dev` should just work, though I have never tried it under mingw. Try using regular Windows terminal (cmd or powershell). If that does not help, please, try setting up the project from scratch and provide the full logs of the whole process

Comment: I tried ```yarn``` and then ```yarn dev``` and it worked! Is it any different that I use regular Windows terminal instead of terminal in VS Code? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving my answer from the comment:

`yarn` and then `yarn dev` should just work. Try using regular Windows terminal (cmd or powershell).

Your VS code seems to use mingw (bash for Windows) environment, which brings its own set of quirks. You may want to switch your default terminal in VS code back to cmd or powershell.

Comment: Sure I will switch that.

Answer (score 1):

Please try `sudo npm install -g asbuild`.

Feel free to +1 on https://github.com/near-examples/guest-book/issues/543

Comment: Nope this does not work in terminal. I got this error: ```'sudo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.```

Comment: ```npm install -g asbuild``` worked! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the update to the sdk was never merged with the example.  I updated it here: https://github.com/near-examples/guest-book/pull/539#pullrequestreview-721177317

Please try again and let me know if the issue is fixed. Thanks!

Comment: it is fixed. Thanks!